# Using HTML5 localstorage as primary data source

Tags: mysql, html, local-storage

Let's say I mandate that users enter their information, which is stored in a MySQL db. To save on server transactions, I store this information in localsource as well. This is the first place the app looks for the data, but falls back to the server data.

Is this a good idea/practice? Does it matter/make a difference?

Comment: What if it's a family and more than one person uses the computer?

Comment: If the data is relatively static, and it doesn't include sensitive information, I think using localstorage like this is fine.

Comment: There are still individual logins, so localstorage will have data for the whole family. Besides, this is an application which will only be used by a single person on a personal computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, thanks to @Rick Hitchcock:

If the data is is relatively static and doesn't include sensitive information, using localstorage like so is acceptable.

I'd add to this that if there are large amounts of data being stored then a different solution (such as caching) should be pursued.